# How do I move values from a single column into individual fields with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I currently have a table of information that looks something like this:

```
ACCTS   |  YEAR  | FEE  
-------------------------    
MBR2056 |  2002  |  25.00  
MBR2058 |  2002  |  12.00  
MBR2060 |  2002  |  15.00  
MBR2056 |  2003  |  25.00  
MBR2060 |  2003  |  10.00
```

And I am trying to break the information out of column 2 (with each year as the header), with fields broken out for each value in the "FEE" column, by year. What I am seeking is something that will look like this:

```
ACCTS   |  2002  |  2003  
-------------------------  
MBR2056 |  25.00 |  25.00  
MBR2058 |  12.00 |  
MBR2060 |  15.00 |  10.00
```

A big part of my problem is that the numbers in the ACCTS column are not sequential, but they are ascending in order. I can group my query by the ACCTS field, but can only collect the data one year at a time. I would really like to break out the FEES values into YEAR columns, and I'm not having much luck. Anyone who can help will be gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you lookup `PIVOT` yet?

Comment: Pivot is the answer. I was just having trouble with the syntax, but I seem to have it worked out now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple pivot will get this results as below:

```
Select * from YourTable
pivot (sum(Fee) for [Year] in ([2002],[2003])) p
```

If you have other columns in that table then

```
Select * from 
   (Select Accts, [Year], Fee from YourTable ) a
   pivot (sum(Fee) for [Year] in ([2002],[2003])) p
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Answer (score 1):

using conditional aggregation to pivot your data:

```
select 
    ACCTS
  , [2002] = max(case when [year] = 2002 then fee end)
  , [2003] = max(case when [year] = 2003 then fee end)
from tbl
group by ACCTS
```

I used `max()` to imply that it was a single source value for `fee`. If you had multiple `fee` per `accts` and `year` then I would have used `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Kannan Kandasamy's answer

If you wish, you can calculate the columns dynamically, either by querying and then building the SQL in VB or by constructing the SQL directly in your query, I implemented this as a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFees AS
BEGIN
  declare @columns nvarchar(max)
  select @columns = coalesce(@columns + ', ', '')+
                    '['+cast(year as varchar(4))+']'
  from (select distinct(year) as year from mytable) x;
  set @columns = 'select * from mytable pivot (sum(fee) for year in ('+
                  @columns + ')) x'
  exec dbo.sp_executesql @columns
END
```

You can then just call the stored procedure dbo.GetFees from your VB code to get the data.

Please note that you have to be certain about the contents of your columns, as this could lead to SQL injection.  You should be fine if the year column is an int.

Comment: Thank you, too. I will make note of using a stored procedure for this.